# Modify the filter chain - Or select servlet to respond to request using filter

Tags: java, filter

I am trying to use a filter to map requests. I am trying to do this for two reasons, firstly to dynamically generate URI's and have them mapped to the appropriate servlet and secondly to catch URI's which are not registered and handle them appropriately.

So I'm using a catch-all filter to process the URI and determine the response. I would like some way of modifying the filter chain, or some way to set the servlet which responds to the request from within the filter. I have been unsuccessful using `filterConfig.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher().forward()` to send to jsp, ideally though I would like to map to a servlet but can't figure out how.

The reason I am not doing this from within a servlet is that I have some URIs which are fixed within web.xml and if I use a catch-all servlet those URIs do not get mapped. Is this possible, is it clean or it going to get really messy?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is the right way to do it.

If you look at what web MVC frameworks do, they have a front controller servlet that maps URLs to controllers, which themselves can accept HTTP requests and return HTTP responses.   I think that's a design worth emulating, not your filter idea.

Comment: OK, so we're talking about a servlet chain? Got an example?

Comment: Sure - Spring MVC.  Except controllers don't extend HttpServlet.